# Get the fragment name or id

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I have a `framelayout` called one time in my `Activity` and various time in other `Fragment` (passing by the same `framelayout` of the `Activity`).

In my `MainActivity.class`, I need to know in what fragment is my `framelayout`.
For example, I need to know if `framelayout` is using `MyFragment1.class` or `MyFragment2.class`.

I need something like this (in this example, the `log` have to say me *"you are in MyFragment1"*):

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.framelayout,new MyFragment1())
        .commit();

if (framelayout.getname.equals("package.MyFragment1.class"))
 Log.d("debug", "you are in MyFragment1");
else if (framelayout.getname.equals("package.MyFragment2.class"))
 Log.d("debug", "you are in MyFragment2");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Look into tag names for fragment manager

Comment: check answer I posted

Comment: I try your solution but it's not working (look at my edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found the solution**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.framelayout,new MyFragment1())
     .commit();

final Fragment fragmentInFrame = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout);

if (fragmentInFrame instanceof MyFragment1){
      Log.d("debug", "you are in MyFragment1");
} else if (fragmentInFrame instanceof MyFragment2) {
      Log.d("debug", "you are in MyFragment2");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use below code to get runtime  **fragment** from `FrameLayout`

```
    Fragment fragmentInFrame = (Fragemnt)getSupportFragmentManager()
                                             .findFragmentById(R.id.frag2_view);
```

then you have check fragment type using  `instanceof`

```
if (fragmentInFrame instanceof MyFragment1){

   Log.d("debug", "you are in MyFragment1");

}else if (fragmentInFrame instanceof MyFragment2){

    Log.d("debug", "you are in MyFragment2");

}
```

Comment: I try your solution but it's not working (look at my edit)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check using instance like

you need to check with your fragment object:

```
 public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
   List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
   if(fragments != null){
    for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
        if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
            return fragment;
    }
   }
   return null;
 }

fragment = getVisibleFragment();
if (fragment instance of MyFragment1){

}
```

Comment: I try a similar solution but it's not working (look at my edit)

Comment: did you get the fragment object first? then after you need to check with instance...

Comment: yes with final Fragment fragmentInFrame = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout);

Comment: then your instance is class of MyFragment1 then it will execute otherwise not.

Answer (score 2):

I Have One `ContentFrameLayout` this Id Is `Fragment_Main`

You Can Use `FrameLayout`

To `Activity` Write This code

```
final Fragment fragmentInFrame = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Fragment_Main);

if(fragmentInFrame instanceof YourFragment){

}
```

To `Fragment` Write This Code

```
final Fragment fragmentInFrame =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Fragment_Main);

if(fragmentInFrame instanceof YourFragment){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final Fragment fragmentInFrame = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.framelayout, new MyFragment1())
     .commit();
```

You are replacing the fragment here. So the `fragmentInFrame` will still refer to old fragment.

So after replacing you need to update `fragmentInFrame` variable by finding it again.

```
fragmentInFrame = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout);
```

Now checking the `fragmentInFrame` will work.

Don't forget to remove the `final` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In your each Fragment class, just define Log inside `onCreateView` method.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer from @Jéwôm' did properly work from me. Note that you must specify the root_framelayout R.id FrameLayout holding all the fragments and implementing non deprecated androidx methods

That's the id used in onPreferenceStartFragment():

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.root_framelayout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```